# What language/syntax is this?

Tags: html

I apologize if this is a super noob question, but I can't seem to find an answer any other way.

I'm trying to figure out what sort of language/syntax I'm looking at. I'm trying to make a few changes to my company's online store. We use 3dCart. 3dCart lets me edit 'Templates'. Here are a few lines.

```
    <!--START: items-->
<tr class="report-font1">
    <td valign="top" align="left" width="15%">[id]</td>
    <td valign="top" align="left" width="53%">[itemname]</td>
    <td valign="top" align="right" width="19%">[itemdescription]</td>
    <td valign="top" align="center" width="9%">[numitems]</td>
</tr>
<!--END: items-->
```

When I view the actual HTML page, the values in brackets are filled in. Where are those values coming from? There doesn't seem to be the right syntax for php or asp (no "echo's" or "print's")
Also, the START and END's must have some significance, because even though they're only used once, the code in between them is repeated for each item.

So is something parsing the code? Is this a common practice? What language/methods are used? I think it's cool and want to learn how to use this, but I don't know where to start. Thanks so much for your help.

Comment: have you at least tried to look it up? http://www.3dcart.com/guide/

Comment: Thanks @valentinas. That's exactly what I needed. I had looked in the support section of the site with little luck. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You said it yourself, and so did Valentinas.  It's the [3dCart](http://www.3dcart.com/guide/) template engine.  Check out the guide and scroll down to the Introduction section.  You'll see a block of markup that looks like what you posted.

Looks like they have all sorts of [support options](http://www.3dcart.com/support.htm) on their website.

Comment: Well, more specifically, this is their custom templating language. Not to be confused with their main product.

Comment: Thanks everyone. Valentina's link was exactly what I needed. Strangely, I couldn't find an article like it in the normal support section of the Site. Thanks again

Comment: @timsum, I found it via a google search for `3dcart template`, though I couldn't find it in their support section either.

Comment: Yeah, I kinda phrased/approached this problem from the wrong direction. I was trying to figure out HOW 3dCart was filling in the brackets, so my searches mainly focused on that question.